# Change Application ID in Visual Studio Ionic project

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-mobile

I have build an Ionic project. When i build it it adds the default appid from ionic. When i want to associate the app with the values frm the store i get this error and can't build the app.

`Warning     The 'Id' attribute is invalid - The value ' 64282WouterDoornbos.Hardloopuitslagen.nl' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/types:ST_ApplicationId' - The Pattern constraint failed. CordovaApp.Windows10    C:\Users\Wouter\OneDrive\Documenten\HardloopUitslagen-Wouter-PC\platforms\windows\package.windows10.appxmanifest    17`

[image: The default ionic windows10.appxmanifest]

The default ionic windows10.appxmanifest

[image: After changing the mainifest.]

After changing the mainifest.

I just can't find a solution to this...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "64282WouterDoornbos" as a part of your application id as it starts with number. Please change it to something like "WouterDoornbos64282".